# Can't compress SVG with GZip

Tags: html, css, .htaccess, svg, gzip

I am trying to use gzip in order to compress svg files and other data.

The code that I've used is the following:

```
<IfModule mod_mime.c>
  AddEncoding gzip svgz
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
  # Compress HTML, CSS, JavaScript, Text, XML and fonts
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/svg+xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/x-icon
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/javascript
</IfModule>
```

Using http://checkgzipcompression.com/ I got some details about what's compressed and what's not.

Technical details
HTTP result 200

Content type    text/html

Compression time    10,818 bytes compressed in 1 millisecond

Execution time of HTTP request  203 milliseconds

Webserver name  Apache/2.4.16

According to https://gtmetrix.com I still need to gzip my svg files.

So is the code wrong? Do I have to specify the type of an svg on each reference (eg. image/svg+xml) or it wouldn't matter?

Let me know please.

An example of an svg reference is:

USING CSS

```
background-image: url("images/logo.svg");
```

USING HTML

```
<img src="http://www.example.com/images/logo.svg" alt="mywebsite">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add (before `AddEncoding`) :

```
AddType image/svg+xml svg svgz
```

Comment: Thanks I tried that too but it didnt work. Do you have any other ideas? Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

If `AddType` doesn't work, try the `.htaccess` file:-

```
<ifModule mod_gzip.c>
mod_gzip_on Yes
mod_gzip_dechunk Yes
mod_gzip_item_include file .(html?|txt|css|js|php|pl|svg)$
...
</ifModule>
```

Failing that, do check your browser's request header. The browser needs to tell the server that it accepts gzip.  Is the gzip library is already installed on server?